# Question on limits of integration and variable substitution: where am I going wrong?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to prove for $x > 0$ that $$
\int_1^{xy} \frac{dt}{t} = \left( \int_1^x \frac{dt}{t} \right) + \left( \int_1^y \frac{dt}{t} \right).
$$

So far I have $$
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_1^{xy} \frac{dt}{t}
&=& \left( \int_1^x \frac{dt}{t} \right) + \left( \int_x^{xy} \frac{dt}{t} \right) \\
&=& \left( \int_1^x \frac{dt}{t} \right) + \left( \int_1^y \frac{dt}{x\cdot t} \right) \\
&=& \left( \int_1^x \frac{dt}{t} \right) + \left( \frac{1}{x} \int_1^y \frac{dt}{t} \right).
\end{eqnarray}
$$

So this is almost correct, but I have an additional factor of $1/x$ in the second term. What am I missing?

P.S. I know this integral is equal to $\log(x)$ and can easily use the fact that $\log(xy) = \log(x) + \log(y)$ but I want to prove the result using methods of integration.

Comment: Double check your substitution - try working through it slowly.

Comment: The substitution is $t=xu$, so $dt=x\,du$ and therefore $\frac{1}{t}\,dt=\frac{1}{xu}x\,du$. With $t=x$, we have $u=1$; with $t=xy$, we have $u=y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all. I guess it's easiest for me to think of things this way. We want to substitute $t \mapsto xs$ which implies $dt = x\,ds$. Trying to think of it in the opposite direction, i.e. $s \mapsto t/x$, seems odd to me (even though it's equivalent).

I guess more generally, is the following rule true?
$$
\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(t)\, dt = \int_a^b f(g(z)) \, g'(z) \, dz
$$
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget the Jacobian
$$
\int_x^{xy}\frac{\mathrm dt}{t}\stackrel{u=t/x}{=}x\int_{1}^y\frac{\mathrm du}{xu}=\int_1^y\frac{\mathrm dt}{t}
$$

Answer (score 0):

After substitution, we have $\displaystyle\int_{x}^{xy}\dfrac{dt}{t}=\int_{1}^{y}\dfrac{ds}{s}$ with $s=\dfrac{t}{x}$, because of that $\dfrac{dt}{t}=\dfrac{ds}{s}$.